# Handling changes in single and multiple select/input in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with two select menus, one input, three buttons, and a checkbox. Everything is added and manipulated by JavaScript. On page page load, there is an object initiated with no values ( either value correspond either one of select or input ). You can select values and update it ( target is array of objects ) in array. Then, you can choose one of the buttons to copy selected options. Each object has three value (copying means that you copy the segment containing those values) times as many as you typed in input. After that, all objects are shown on screen. You can click a button to check all checkboxes and all objects change value. Value is updated in all selects of changed type and in the corresponding array.
Now **my problems begin.** When you unselect all checkboxes and want to change **only 1 object** all objects are updated and I have no idea why. There are conditions to check for each object if the checkbox is unchecked.  If a single  object is updated (either select or input) all of the other objects are updated ( none of checkbox is checked).
Here is github link to this project to check everything out without problems.
Also one more thing... whenever I update all values handleDOMChange function should fire automatically, but as you can see I have to fire it up manually so the changes are "visible" on my target array

```
const collectedData = [ {
    cableType: "",
    calbleLen_m: 0,
    deviceType: ""
} ];
const completeData = {};
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {   

    handleButtonEvents();

    const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.installationSegment');
    segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
        handleInputAndSelectChange(segment, i);
    });

    const targetNode = document.getElementById("installationContainer");
    targetNode.append(selectAllCheckboxesButton);

    const config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true
    };
   const observer = new MutationObserver(handleDOMChange);
   observer.observe(targetNode, config);    
}
```

```
    //Handling DOMChanges
        const handleDOMChange = function() {
            const powerSupplyElement = document.getElementById('powerSupply');
            powerSupplyElement.addEventListener('change', e => completeData.supplyType = e.target.value);
            const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.installationSegment');
            if( segments.length >= 2 ) {
                segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
                    const checkbox = segment.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
                    if( !checkbox.checked ) {
                        //updating value for single change, i is index of element in array and none of checkboxes is checked.
                        handleInputAndSelectChange(segment, i);
                    } else if( checkbox.checked ) {
                        //updating value for every segment exisitng in DOM whose checkbox has been checked. 
                        handleManySegmentsChange(segment);
                    }
                });
            }
        
            completeData.bus = [ ...collectedData ];
            console.table(completeData.bus);
        }
```

```
//handling ButtonEvents
handleButtonEvents = function() {
    const installationSegment = document.getElementById('installationContainer');
    installationSegment.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if( e.target.id.includes("Skopiuj") ) {
            handleCopyNthTimes(e);
        } else if( e.target.id.includes("Usun") ) {
            handleDeleteDevice(e);
        } else if( e.target.id === 'selectAllCheckboxes' ) {
            checkAllCheckboxes(e);
        }
    });
}
```

```
//handling all checkboxes select and unselect
const checkAllCheckboxes = function() {
    const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.installationSegment');
    segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
        const checkbox = segment.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        handleDOMChange();
    });
};
```

```
//handling single and multiple changes in select/input
handleManySegmentsChange = function(segment) {
    segment.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        switch( e.target.name ) {
            case 'cableSelect': {
                const cableSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.cableSelect');
                cableSelect.forEach(cable => cable.value = e.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(cable => cable.cableType = e.target.value);
                handleDOMChange();
                break;
            }
            case 'deviceSelect': {
                const deviceSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.deviceSelect');
                deviceSelect.forEach(device => device.value = e.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(device => device.deviceType = e.target.value);
                handleDOMChange();
                break;
            }
            case 'cableInput': {
                const cableInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cableInput"]');
                cableInput.forEach(input => input.value = e.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(input => input.calbleLen_m = parseInt(e.target.value));
                handleDOMChange();
                break;
            }
        }
    })

}

handleInputAndSelectChange = function(segment, index) {
    segment.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        switch( event.target.name ) {
            case 'cableSelect': {
                collectedData[index].cableType = event.target.value;
                break;
            }
            case 'deviceSelect': {
                collectedData[index].deviceType = event.target.value;
                break;
            }
            case 'cableInput': {
                collectedData[index].calbleLen_m = parseInt(event.target.value);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: also one more thing... whenever I update all values `handleDOMChange` function should fire automatically, but as you can see I have to fire it up manually so the changes are "visible" on my target array.

Comment: Please, make a snippet with your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/os5Lyjr4/3/
The situation I mean is select all checkboxes, change value of all inputs, then unselect all checkboxes ( the same button ) and then try to change value of one item

Comment: Welcome!
Your "one more thing" should be added to the question by editing it = the comment could get lost/not seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I've found the answer. The reason it didn't work is that `handleManySegmentsChange` function is going to be fired in one circumstance - if user changes many select values **at once**. But this cannot be the case. My solution to the problem is to detect one change in segment, check for checkbox value, pass it to the function and depending on the checkbox value either update one value or all of them. Like so:

```
const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.installationSegment');
    segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
        segment.addEventListener('change', e => {
            const checkbox = segment.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
            handleInputAndSelectChange(segment, e, i, checkbox.checked);
        })
    });
```

and then in function

```
handleInputAndSelectChange = function(segment, event, index, checked) {
    switch( event.target.name ) {
        case 'cableSelect': {
            if( checked ) {
                const cableSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.cableSelect');
                cableSelect.forEach(cable => cable.value = event.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(data => data.cableType = event.target.value);
            } else if( !checked ) {
                collectedData[index].cableType = event.target.value;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'deviceSelect': {
            if( checked ) {
                const deviceSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.deviceSelect');
                deviceSelect.forEach(device => device.value = event.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(device => device.deviceType = event.target.value);
            } else if( !checked ) {
                collectedData[index].deviceType = event.target.value;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 'cableInput': {
            if( checked ) {
                const cableInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cableInput"]');
                cableInput.forEach(input => input.value = event.target.value);
                collectedData.forEach(input => input.calbleLen_m = parseInt(event.target.value));
            } else if( !checked ) {
                collectedData[index].calbleLen_m = parseInt(event.target.value);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```